# Existence of solidity witness implies the existence of standard solidity witness

Tags: proof-explanation, set-theory

My question comes from M. Zeman' and R. Schindler's fine structure article in the handbook of set theory, the proof of lemma $7.4$. I understand most of the proof, except for one crucial claim, which I don't see how to prove.

First let $M$ be acceptable and $\nu\in p\in P_M$ and let $(W, r)$ be a witness for $\nu\in p$ w.r.t. $M, p$ such that $W\in M$. We want to show that $W^{\nu,p}_M \in M$, i.e. $M$ has the standard witness.

Now we let $\sigma:W^{\nu,p}_M\rightarrow_1 M$ be the inverse of the collapsing function, and we construct some $\sigma^*:W^{\nu,p}_M \rightarrow_1 \bar{W}$, where $\bar{W} = J^A_\alpha$, $\alpha = \mbox{sup}(h_W(\nu\cup \{r\})\cap\mbox{On})$ and $W = J^A_\beta$ for some $\beta \ge \alpha$. Now the authors assume wlog that $W^{\nu,p}_M$ is not an initial segment of $M$. Then it is shown that $\nu$ must be the critical point of $\sigma$. Then it is mentioned that if $M = J^B_\gamma$, then we know that $\sigma(\nu)$ is regular in $M$ and that $J^B_{\sigma(\nu)}\models\mbox{ZFC}^-$. And that we may code $W^{\nu,p}_M$ by some $a\subseteq \nu$, $\Sigma_1$-definably over $W^{\nu,p}_M$. $(*)$ And using $\sigma^*$ we have $a\in M$, in fact $a\in J^B_{\sigma(\nu)}$ by acceptability. And now, we can decode $a$ in $J^B_{\sigma(\nu)}$ and so $W^{\nu,p}_M \in J^B_{\sigma(\nu)} \subseteq M$.

Now I have the following question:

My question is about $(*)$. I don't see how we can code all of $W^{\nu,p}_M$ in some $a \subseteq \nu$, without using the parameter $\sigma^{-1}(p\setminus\nu+1)$. And that's because we only have $W^{\nu,p}_M = h_{W^{\nu,p}_M}"(\nu\cup \{\sigma^{-1}(p\setminus\nu+1)\})$. But if we manage to show that $p\setminus\nu+1\in J^B_{\sigma(\nu)}$, then we can use $p\setminus\nu+1$ as a parameter to define $a$ and decode it in $J^B_{\sigma(\nu)}$. Can we show this? Or is there another way to code $a$?

I would appreciate any hints or remarks for my above question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set $a$ is taken to incorporate the relevant information about $\sigma^{-1}(p\backslash(\nu+1))$ (and parameters ${<\nu}$). But since $\sigma^{-1}(p\backslash(\nu+1))$
is finite, we don't actually need to literally refer to that object itself; it can be coded.

That is, what one wants, uncoded, is the $\Sigma_1$-theory in $M$ of parameters in $\nu\cup\{p\backslash(\nu+1)\})$. But let's modify this slightly, and instead let $t$ be the set of all pairs $(\varphi,\vec{x})$ such that $\varphi$ is a $\Sigma_1$ formula (in the appropriate language), $\vec{x}\in\nu^{<\omega}$ and $M\models\varphi(\vec{x},p\backslash(\nu+1))$. So $t\subseteq\omega\times\nu^{<\omega}$, but use a simply definable bijection to convert this to a subset $a\subseteq\nu$. This is the kind of set $a$ you want to use.

(Another standard way to proceed is to replace the set $\nu\cup\{p\backslash(\nu+1)\}$ with $\nu$, by replacing (the finitely many elements in) $p\backslash(\nu+1)$ with some integers $0,1,\ldots,k-1$, and shifting the original integers up by $k$ to avoid conflicts.)

Comment: About the notation, you are absolutely right, it's a typo. And about the solution you kindly provided, I have a little bit of trouble understanding part of it. So we can easily decode $t$ from $a$, in $J^B_{\sigma(\nu)}$. But what is confusing to me, is don't see how we decode $W^{\nu, p}_M$ from $t$ using $h_M$, while not having the parameter $p\setminus \nu+1$ in $J^B_{\sigma(\nu)}$. Maybe I'm missing something again and maybe even $p\setminus \nu+1 \in J^B_{\sigma(\nu)}$. Can you please elaborate more on this?

Comment: Oh I think I can remedy the approach; maybe if we define $\bar{\in} \subseteq ([\nu]^{<\omega})^2$, by $(\xi_1, \dots, \xi_n) \bar{\in} (\eta_1, \dots, \eta_m)$ iff $h_{W^{\nu, p}_M}(\xi_1, \dots, \xi_n, \sigma^{-1}(p\setminus \nu+1)) \in h_{W^{\nu, p}_M}(\eta_1, \dots, \eta_m, \sigma^{-1}(p\setminus \nu+1))$, then we may code $\bar{\in}$ as some $a \subseteq \nu$ and then use transitive collapse in $J^B_{\sigma(\nu)}$ on $\bar{\in}$ to get $W^{\nu, p}_M$, right?

Comment: Yes, right. (Note those membership statements in your comment are encoded into the $\Sigma_1$ theory.) (Regarding the first comment, if $p\backslash(\nu+1)\neq\emptyset$ then it is $\notin J^B_{\sigma(\nu)}$, as it is in the range of $\sigma$, so its minimum is $\geq\sigma(\nu)$.)

Comment: Oh, right. I guess it could also be extracted from the $\Sigma_1$ theory. I guess I need to think more on how one may (de)code information (from/)into these objects/theories. Thanks!